# What all can be found from the given information?

Tags: self-study, variance, mean, median, range

Sums and products of every pair of n numbers are given, however it is not known as which pair's sum and product they are. From this information we can find:
a) Mean of the n numbers
b)Variance of the n numbers
c)Median of n numbers
d)Range of the numbers
I know that mean and variance can be found since we would be able to find the sum of the numbers and the sum of their squares.
What about **Median** and **range**?

Comment: This reads like an assigned question. Is it for a class?

Comment: Nope. Its from previous year questions of an entrance exam i want to give

Comment: Then it counts as `self-study`. Please add the tag and read its [tag wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info) and modify your question accordingly. In particular, you'd need to show a proper attempt at these questions about which we might give some guidance, What are your thoughts?